# How to include libraries during war file built in spring project?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a spring project and it is running well. The problem is, whenever I perform a new deployment using the war file in tomcat, I need to manually copy the libraries in the lib folder. I am wondering if there is any way to add those libraries inside the war file so that every time I don't need to waste my time by copying the libraries in the server. It needs to be automatically included from the generated war file.

Comment: And how do you build the WAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer depends on how you are building your WAR but I assume you are using one of the popular build tools for Java. Given that your war does not have a populated lib folder I'm assuming you have either not configured the right plugins for these build tools or you are compiling and managing your classpath from the command line like a madman. If the later is the case then I highly suggest you start using a build tool for your projects (All IDE's do this by default), if the former is the case I refer you to the individual pages for the plugins:

**Maven**:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/index.html

The war plugin does this by default.

**Gradle**: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html

The War plugin for Gradle also does this by default.

**Ant**: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html

A glossary reading for the Ant tasks did not reveal if it did so by default but I'm assuming it does.

Comment: I am using netbeans 8.1 ide.

Comment: I figured out that you are right. I had exclude lib folder tag in my war setup file and that is why I was not getting the libraries inside the war.